# Trigger pipeline build from sub directory in a monorepo

Tags: git, continuous-integration, cd, monorepo

We're interested in moving a monorepo to git and would like to integrate it with a pipeline based CI/CD.

The general pattern we've seen so far is a single pipeline description file at the root of the repo, which implies a single pipeline per repo. This seems to be the pattern followed by Jenkins Pipeline, Gitlab, Bitbucket CI, CircleCI and others.

Given a monorepo, we would like multiple such files, one for each project in the repo.

Is there a pipeline style CI that does this?

The other alternative we can think of is a pipeline description file for all projects with custom filtering. Do any of the existing pipeline CI systems handle this without extra tooling?

Comment: Questions for recommendations or finding tools are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. Most of the cloud based CI systems i've used don't support this. But if you are open to a local system, Atlassian Bamboo can support this (single repository but multiple different plans for that one repository). Though, Bamboo can't be configured via files and is pretty cumbersome to use.

Comment: Probably on-topic on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a good solution for that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to bring your own solution by [checking all the projects impacted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564421/get-a-list-of-all-1st-level-directories-impacted-by-recent-commits-for-a-git-mon) by the commits which the CI has checked-out.

Once you have your list of projects you run all the tasks you need to run on each one of the projects impacted by changes.

Answer (score 1):

I created some showcase for monorepo with [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) as build tool
and [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) or [Bitbucket pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) as CI tool.

See:
https://github.com/zladovan/monorepo

Gradle specific stuff should be replaceable quite easily by something else. Just change `tools/ci/core/list-dependencies.sh`.