# get a list of all 1st level directories impacted by recent commits for a git monorepo

Tags: shell, output, monorepo

I am currently playing with monorepos and I am trying to retrieve a list all 1 level subfolders in the repo which are impacted since a given commit.

So far I can retrieve all the files impacted using `git diff --name-only $COMMIT_ID..head`

Using `git diff --name-only $COMMIT_ID..head | xargs -L1 dirname` I manage to get only the folder names.

To remove all the duplicates I added `sort | uniq` to the mix: `git diff --name-only $COMMIT_ID..head | xargs -L1 dirname | sort | uniq`

All I need now is to ensure I only retrieve the first level folders i.e. `project1` not `project1/src` and `project1/lib`

I have tried a few options but I have not managed to keep it as a one liner so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `awk`

```
git diff --name-only $COMMIT_ID | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u
```

- `-F'/'` sets the delimiter field to slash `/`
- `NF!=1{print $1}` prints out the first field which is the first level directory name if the line contain slashes `/`, this filters out files that exists in the first level

  ```
  readme.md          NF==1
  project1/file      NF==2
  project2/src/file  NF==3
  ```
- `sort -u` combined sort and unique

Comment: Perfect! I was missing the `NF!=1` for awk. Thank you!

Comment: @Coyote Glad to help! The option `--dirstat` of `git diff` might also come in handy if you want to view the percentage of changes in each directory, however this will include subdirectories as well